# Difference between using the Queue class in ruby versus using an array to implement a queue

Tags: ruby, algorithm, performance, queue

In ruby if i want to implement a queue, then either i can use the Queue class of the standard library or i can use an array with methods push and shift to enqueue and dequeue an item respectively in the queue.
Is there any performance difference in the two approaches for implementing a queue in ruby or are they the same ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Queue](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html) class is used to synchronize communication between threads.  You would use this if you were doing something with concurrency.

For your purposes, you should use an Array.

Comment: Actually it’s worth mentioning that `Array#shift` is amortized constant complexity, while `Array#unshift` is not. So it’s better to use `#push` and `#shift` (like mentioned in question) than `#unshift` and `#pop`.

Answer (score 0):

A ruby array implements the two methods you need -- push and pop -- but I'm not sure it cleans up it's internal array so might not be great if you've pushed a lot of data, then popped.

A better way might be to implement yourself and manage a linked list. [here](https://gist.github.com/ggilder/3224402) is an example of a linked-list based stack, which might be easy to modify.

Uncertain of license so I'm not posting someone else's code.

Comment: You can't use ruby arrays push and pop methods for a queue, they will make a stack since push pushes on the same side as pop (the end). You can just use an array, but you need to use unshift and pop, (or shift and push)